# How to populate a paginated RecyclerView with multiple sections and data sources for each section?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination

Consider the following structure for a `RecyclerView`

```
Header: Type -> Header
Data 1: Type -> Data, Category -> Category1
Data 2: Type -> Data, Category -> Category1
Data 3: Type -> Data, Category -> Category1
...

Header: Type -> Header
Data 4: Type -> Data, Category -> Category2
Data 5: Type -> Data, Category -> Category2
Data 6: Type -> Data, Category -> Category2
...

Header: Type -> Header
Data 7: Type -> Data, Category -> Category3
Data 8: Type -> Data, Category -> Category3
Data 9: Type -> Data, Category -> Category3
...
```

Here, I have 2 ViewTypes in my RecyclerView: `Header` and `Data`. Each section of the `RecyclerView` is paginated and I have to get data in chunks whenever I reach the bottom of a section through different API calls based on the `Category` of data. I have made the complete working structure of `RecyclerView` and it is working fine, but pagination is not working. Since this is a single list that I am populating, how can I know which section I am currently at and make the respective API call based on the `Category` of that section? Is it even possible? If not, what are some possible workarounds?

PS: Using multiple `RecyclerView`s is not an option since this is a resource constrained environment I am working in.

Comment: You should use expandable list view in this case.

Comment: You are create your POJO 
One Main List 
In Main List create one more list for children's of main list 
While You pagination then you init two recycler view 
Child recycler view in main recycler view